# Slide issues with my image slider on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Hey so the problem I am having is on my website www.stallionstride.org .

The image slider works when my buttons are pressed slowly, however, if you press the left and right buttons quickly when my images should slide back the other way instead it slides to an empty spot.

I tried using the stop command but that has not worked for me.

Here is my code. I only included the right buttons event since the left is basically the same.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$('#rightbutton').click(function() {
    //clear the timer since photos scroll through at a certain amount of time

    clearTimeout(timeoutTracker);
    var scrollAmount = $('#slideshow_inner img').width();
    var currentPos = Math.abs(parseInt($('#slideshow_inner').css('left')));

    var remainingScroll = ($('#slideshow_inner').width() - currentPos)/908;

    if (remainingScroll == 1) {
        $('#slideshow_inner').stop(true, false).animate({ 'left' : '0' }, 'slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#slideshow_inner').stop(true, false).animate({ 'left' : '-=' + scrollAmount}, 'slow');
    }
    timeoutTracker = setTimeout(function() {$('#rightbutton').click(); }, 3000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sliding images requires more design especially with back/next button.

I would suggest well developed plugin instead of building on your own.

One I can think of is `slidejs`, http://www.slidesjs.com/